# Comparing the time complexity of two algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The question suggests two algorithms spend T_A(n)=0.0001n^2, and T_B(n)=50√n, microseconds respectively, for a problem size of n. The question asks, at what input size will Algorithm A become better than B. How do I find this?

I found a similar question with a solution that I don't fully understand. The running times of algorithms from the similar question are T_A = 0.1n^2logn (base 2) and T_B = 2.5n^2

It's solved as follows:

```
2.5n^2 < 0.1n^2 log2 n
2.5 < 0.1 log2 n
25 < log2 n
2^25 < n
```

Therefore, Algorithm 2 is better when n is greater than 2^25

Comment: You need to solve the inequality `T_A(n)<T_B(n)` for `n`, as it is done in the example you found.

Comment: This question is better suited for cs SE or math SE.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the two algorithms solve the same problem. In that case you can say that Algorithm A is better than B if `T_A` < `T_B`, because the former runs in a shorter time.

For which values of n does that `T_A` < `T_B` inequality hold?
Substituting the expressions of  `T_A` and `T_B` you get

[image]

You can learn how one can solve an inequality of this kind with pen and paper e.g. [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:solve-equations-inequalities/x2f8bb11595b61c86:multistep-inequalities/v/multi-step-inequalities-3), or [solve it graphically and algebraically using an engine for symbolic math like Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.0001n%5E2+%3C+50%E2%88%9An).
If you do that, you will see that `T_A` is smaller than `T_B` only if n is smaller than some threshold value. Beyond that threshold, B "gets better than A" because a square root function (like `T_B`) increases more slowly than a quadratic one (like `T_A`) as n increases.